# char and char& no matching function for call

Tags: c++, c++11

In order to compare if two string contain a same char, I was trying to loop through a string a and put the chars into a map.

So this is what I did.

```
string a = "abc";
unordered_map<char,int> m;

for (auto i:a){
    m.insert(i,1);
}
```

But then there is an error:
`no matching function for call to ‘std::unordered_map<char, int>::insert(char&, int)’`

I don't quite understand what can I do here.  Hope someone can help!

Comment: `i` is your char, not `a`.

Comment: C++ has set, `std::set` and `std::unordered_set`.

Comment: Try [Rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: The reason for your compiler error is that you wrote `m.insert(a,1);` instead of `m.insert(i,1);`. But you really should change to a different datastructure, like e.g. `std::set` or `std::unordered_set` (e.g. see Patryk's answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you try to insert `a` which is a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) into an `std::unordered_map<char, int>` - you should be inserting `i` which is a `char` (each `char` from `std::string a`).

Moreover, even if you correctly used

```
m.insert(a,1);
```

it wouldn't compile because [`std::unordered_map::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert) accepts a [`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) not 2 arguments from the template type. So you would need:

```
std::unordered_map<char, int> char_map;
char_map.insert(std::make_pair(c, 1));
```

Want you want to achieve can be done with [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) (if you don't care about the order of objects - chars - stored inside it)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>

int main()
{
   std::string a = "abc";
   std::unordered_set<char> char_set;

   for (auto c : a)
     char_set.insert(c);

   for (auto c : char_set)
       std::cout << c << ' ';
}
```

http://cpp.sh/3zrgr

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you need to call `std::make_pair` first:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

int main() 
{
    std::string a = "abc";
    std::unordered_map<char,int> m;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i)
        m.insert(std::make_pair(a[i],1));
}
```